# I need keep my login session for 2 hours in application

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have tried in local that mean application source code it working.but when i was deploy in live server that time is not working.that session will expired in 20 mins. below i mention the code

Comment: in web config
  <system.web>
    <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="120"></sessionState>
</system.web>
 in global.asax.cs
  void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Session.Timeout = 120;
        }

Comment: What did you try until now ?

Comment: Do you use IIS to publish?

Comment: -Regular Time Interval, -Idle Time-out, -Limit Interval,       can you say which values do you see on your IIS settings for these fields?

Comment: yeah i am IIS for publish the file, I tried  in web config <system.web> <sessionState mode="InProc" timeout="120"></sessionState> </system.web> in global.asax.cs void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) { Session.Timeout = 120; }

Comment: @Anand please edit this information into the question rather than posting it as comments.